# How to add a domready event to an infoBubble

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I've been using infoWindows, but due to the desire to change the layout of the infoWindow, I'm trying to switch to an infoBubble.  However, the domready event isn't executing like it did for the infoWindow.  I'm a javascipt hacker, so please explain this to me in terms that a hacker can understand.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
var infoWindow = new InfoBubble({content: request.responseText, 
   maxWidth: 1000, position: latLng, arrowSize: 0, maxHeight: 600});
infoWindow.open(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, "domready", function() {load_rotator();});
```

Thanks in advance!

-- Geoff

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what I've used in the past to attach listeners to an infobubble:

```
    myInfoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        id: myID,
        content: 'some content',
        hideCloseButton: false,
        backgroundColor: '#004475',
        borderColor: '#004475'
    });

    var myMarker =  new google.maps.Marker({
            id: markerID,
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            icon: icon
    }); 

                google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() { 
                                    myInfoBubble.open(myMap, myMarker); 
                });
```